# get rid of x if no extension given for phone field in Jquery masked input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput, jquery-mask

Im using [jquery Masked](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo) input plugin.

I have the following mask on a field:

```
 "?999-999-9999 x9999"
```

Why `?` in begining? because if user entered incomplete number, i dont want the field to clear out so i made the whole thing optional. now when user is entering the numbers is able to see `x` always whether or not a phone has extension. How do i get rid of that `x` if no extension was given?

Again i do not want to clear out the field, if i use

```
  "999-999-9999? x9999"
```

yes it works it adds x only when it has extension but if incomplete phone entered it empties the field which is not the goal.

Any help is appreciated thanks alot.

Comment: The [demo](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo) already seems to have something like that...

Comment: nope the demo has second version that i have which clears out the text if incomplete phone is given.

Comment: Ah, I see. No idea, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying alot i fixed it myself to accomplish the goal.

Goal was to keep text not disappearing if incomplete input was given and to get rid of x if no extension was given.

I added this test at the end of code:

```
var splitString = $("[name=myinput]").val().split("x");
//if splitString array length is more than 1 means splitString[1] is set
//if splitString[1].length is 0 means its only x by itself so get rid of it
if (splitString.length > 1 && splitString[1].length == 0) {
    $("[name=myinput]").val($("[name=myinput]").val().replace("x", ""));
}
```

examples:

```
 entered text: 718-111-123 x -> turns into -> 718-111-123
 entered text: 718-111     x -> turns into -> 718-111
 entered text: 718-111-123 x555 -> turns into -> 718-111-123 x555
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to do the same thing. This is where I landed.

`$('input.phone').inputmask('999-999-9999[ x999999]', { placeholder: ' ', greedy: false });`

This doesn't cut the x off like your examples. But I liked how simple it is, and how it adds the x automatically after hitting space after the phone number. So I thought it was worth sharing, especially because I feel the docs for this plugin are lacking a little bit.